# How to work around NHibernate caching?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm new to NHibernate and was assigned to a task where I have to change a value of an entity property and then compare if this new value (cached) is different from the actual value stored on the DB. However, every attempt to retrieve this value from the DB resulted in the cached value. As I said, I'm new to NHibernate, maybe this is something easy to do and obviously could be done with plain ADO.NET, but the client demands that we use NHibernate for every access to the DB. In order to make things clearer, those were my "successful" attempts (ie, no errors):

## 1

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<User>()
.SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property(UserField.JobLoad)))
.Add(Expression.Eq(UserField.Id, userid));

return GetByDetachedCriteria(criteria)[0].Id; //this is the value I want
```

## 2

```
var JobLoadId = DetachedCriteria.For<User>()
.SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property(UserField.JobLoad)))
.Add(Expression.Eq(UserField.Id, userid));

ICriteria criteria = JobLoadId.GetExecutableCriteria(NHibernateSession);

var ids = criteria.List();
return ((JobLoad)ids[0]).Id;
```

Hope I made myself clear, sometimes is hard to explain a problem when even you don't quite understand the underlying framework.

Edit: Of course, this is a method body.

Edit 2: I found out that it doesn't work properly for the method call is inside a transaction context. If I remove the transaction, it works fine, but I need it to be in this context.

Answer (score 3):

I do that opening a new stateless session for geting the actual object in the database:

```
 User databaseuser;
 using (IStatelessSession session = SessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
                {
                databaseuser =  db.get<User>("id"); 
                }
//do your checks
```

Answer (score 2):

Within a session, NHibernate will return the same object from its Level-1 Cache (aka Identity Map). If you need to see the current value in the database, you can open a new session and load the object in that session.

Answer (score 0):

*googles nhforge*

http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/finding-dirty-properties-in-nhibernate.html

This may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
public class MyObject : Entity
{
   private readonly string myField;

   public string MyProperty 
   { 
     get { return myField; }
     set 
    {
       if (value != myField)
       {
          myField = value;
          DoWhateverYouNeedToDoWhenItIsChanged();
       }
    }
   }
}
```